# netsh wifi hotspot config max clients

Tags: wifi-configuration, hotspot, netsh

I've set up a wifi hotspot on my computer using netsh commands.

I would like to know if it is possible to change the max number of clients ("netsh wlan show hostednetwork" shows maxclients=100).

I suppose it is using the command "netsh wlan set profileparameter" but I do not manage to use it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: May be here have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168152/use-netsh-wlan-set-hostednetwork-to-create-a-wifi-hotspot-and-the-authenti whether this get you with some idea.

Comment: Thanks for your link but I do not see where it tells about my problem. Actualy, my hostednetwork works perfectly. It is just that it seems to be opened to 100 clients. Of course I've set up a strong password but for security reasons I would like to reduce the number of simultaneous clients connected. How could I do this using netsh?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I wanted to limit the count of users to 1 (my mobile device only). I found the solution myself:

1. Open Registry Editor (regedit.exe) and navigate to:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WlanSvc\Parameters\HostedNetworkSettings`
2. Open HostedNetworkSettings (REG_BINARY)
3. Edit offset *64*, (value *64 hex* = *100 decimal*) to any other value like **01** for one user only (or **FF** for 255 count of users)
4. Restart services: *dot3svc*, *WlanSvc*
5. Start *hostednetwork* again